# Apostrophe (') in excel not hiding

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating an excel file from HTML string. In it I wanted to add an apostrophe before a phone number because excel converts the phone number in the form of `e` like `1+e23`. I wanted to show phone number as a phone number.

The HTML adds that apostrophe but when converted to excel the apostrophe is shown as it is like this

[image]

Even this shows as apostrophe in print preview.

However, when I try to edit the cell and simply press enter without changing the content, it hides the apostrophe in excel.

[image]

I need to know why it does not gets hidden in the first place.

Comment: Wasn't me but you should show the code that adds the apostrophe (or code that reproduces this issue)

Comment: Excel's 'rules' when importing are confusing. What you are getting is akin to trying to populate a formula in a cell with the formula correctly determined as the value of a field in a CSV. The formula comes in as text until F2, Enter is used to have Excel re-evaluate the contents into a working formula. At the same time, textual numbers or postal codes with leading zeroes are routinely evaluated as true numbers and are often put into a scientific notation format due to column width. Run Text-to-Columns►Fixed Width on each offending column or use Data import, marking the fields as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have alluded to, there are sometimes differences between what excel imports and what it evaluates (after the cell edit).

For me, the best way around this would be to set the cell value as text to begin with. You don't say how you're producing the Excel file from the Html but I'd guess you're just producing a .csv?

An open xml library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) makes writing text to the cell easy (even where the text it would look like a number to Excel's import if written to a csv).

For example:

```
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Tel. No as number:";
            ws.Cells["B1"].Value = 1231231234;
            ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "Tel. No as text:";
            ws.Cells["B2"].Value = "1231231234";

            ws.Column(1).AutoFit();
            ws.Column(2).AutoFit();

            excelPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\OutputExample.xlsx"));
        }
```

This displays cell B2 without the leading apostrophe without having to evaluate the cell.